# Remove objects in an array based on another array of objects where specific property values match

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays (below) - I would like to modify the `relatedCards` array to not include the objects that are present in `ownedCards` array where values of `relatedCards.series` and `ownedCards.series` are the same and `relatedCards.card_number` and `ownedCards.card_number` are also the same.

```
let relatedCards = [
   {
      "brand":"National Treasures",
      "card_number":"43",
      "manufacturer":"Panini",
      "series":"Rookie Patch Autographs",
      "year":"2017"
   },
   {
      "brand":"National Treasures",
      "card_number":"4",
      "manufacturer":"Panini",
      "series":"2014 National Notable Nicknames",
      "year":"2017"
   },
   {
      "brand":"National Treasures",
      "card_number":"99",
      "manufacturer":"Panini",
      "series":"Collegiate Materials Signatures Silver",
      "year":"2017"
   },
   {
      "brand":"National Treasures",
      "card_number":"199",
      "manufacturer":"Panini",
      "series":"Collegiate Materials Signatures Silver",
      "year":"2017"
   }
]


let ownedCards = [
   {
      "brand":"National Treasures",
      "card_number":"43",
      "manufacturer":"Panini",
      "series":"Rookie Patch Autographs",
      "year":"2017"
   },
   {
      "brand":"National Treasures",
      "card_number":"4",
      "manufacturer":"Panini",
      "series":"2014 National Notable Nicknames",
      "year":"2017"
   },
   {
      "brand":"National Treasures",
      "card_number":"411",
      "manufacturer":"Panini",
      "series":"Collegiate Materials",
      "year":"2017"
   }
]
```

Based on the above two array the output of new array should be

```
[   
   {
      "brand":"National Treasures",
      "card_number":"99",
      "manufacturer":"Panini",
      "series":"Collegiate Materials Signatures Silver",
      "year":"2017"
   },
   {
      "brand":"National Treasures",
      "card_number":"199",
      "manufacturer":"Panini",
      "series":"Collegiate Materials Signatures Silver",
      "year":"2017"
   }
]
```

What is the most performant way to achieve this?

Comment: So none of these were of any help? https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+merge+two+arrays+site:stackoverflow.com&client=safari&rls=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiSx7T5g4HvAhVBU80KHSg8AfgQrQIoBHoECAUQBQ&biw=1792&bih=929

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method is to use `filter` and `some`.

```js
let relatedCards = [ { "brand":"National Treasures", "card_number":"43", "manufacturer":"Panini", "series":"Rookie Patch Autographs", "year":"2017" }, { "brand":"National Treasures", "card_number":"4", "manufacturer":"Panini", "series":"2014 National Notable Nicknames", "year":"2017" }, { "brand":"National Treasures", "card_number":"99", "manufacturer":"Panini", "series":"Collegiate Materials Signatures Silver", "year":"2017" }, { "brand":"National Treasures", "card_number":"199", "manufacturer":"Panini", "series":"Collegiate Materials Signatures Silver", "year":"2017" } ]; let ownedCards = [ { "brand":"National Treasures", "card_number":"43", "manufacturer":"Panini", "series":"Rookie Patch Autographs", "year":"2017" }, { "brand":"National Treasures", "card_number":"4", "manufacturer":"Panini", "series":"2014 National Notable Nicknames", "year":"2017" }, { "brand":"National Treasures", "card_number":"411", "manufacturer":"Panini", "series":"Collegiate Materials", "year":"2017" } ];

let res = relatedCards.filter(x => !ownedCards
  .some(y => y.card_number === x.card_number && y.series === x.series));
console.log(res);
```

To speed this up, a `Set` can be used.

```js
let relatedCards = [ { "brand":"National Treasures", "card_number":"43", "manufacturer":"Panini", "series":"Rookie Patch Autographs", "year":"2017" }, { "brand":"National Treasures", "card_number":"4", "manufacturer":"Panini", "series":"2014 National Notable Nicknames", "year":"2017" }, { "brand":"National Treasures", "card_number":"99", "manufacturer":"Panini", "series":"Collegiate Materials Signatures Silver", "year":"2017" }, { "brand":"National Treasures", "card_number":"199", "manufacturer":"Panini", "series":"Collegiate Materials Signatures Silver", "year":"2017" } ]; let ownedCards = [ { "brand":"National Treasures", "card_number":"43", "manufacturer":"Panini", "series":"Rookie Patch Autographs", "year":"2017" }, { "brand":"National Treasures", "card_number":"4", "manufacturer":"Panini", "series":"2014 National Notable Nicknames", "year":"2017" }, { "brand":"National Treasures", "card_number":"411", "manufacturer":"Panini", "series":"Collegiate Materials", "year":"2017" } ];

let ownedSet = new Set(ownedCards.map(x => x.card_number + " / " + x.series));
let res = relatedCards.filter(x => !ownedSet.has(x.card_number + " / " + x.series));
console.log(res);
```